# Androidplot: create Timeline

Tags: android, graph, charts, androidplot

Short Question:

How can I set the X Axis of a Androidplot to Calendar (Date&Time) Elements?

```
for(int i=1; i<sY.length;i++)
{
    Log.d("Watcher","sY:"+sY[i]);
    nY[i] = (Number)Double.parseDouble(sY[i]);
}
for(int i=1; i<sX.length;i++)
{
    Log.d("Watcher","sX: "+sX[i]);      
    nX[i] = (Number)Double.parseDouble(sX[i]);
}

XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(nY), 
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY,
                getTitle);

LineAndPointFormatter seriesFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                Color.rgb(0, 200, 0), // line color
                Color.rgb(0, 100, 0), // point color
                Color.rgb(150, 190, 150)); // fill color (optional)

oneChart.addSeries(series, seriesFormat);           

oneChart.disableAllMarkup();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private class MyDateFormat extends Format { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DDD:kk/mm/ss");

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        long timestamp = ((Number) obj).longValue();
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
        return dateFormat.format(date, toAppendTo, pos);
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
        return null;    
    }
}

oneChart.setDomainValueFormat(new MyDateFormat());
```